# How to embed interactive graphs without using bokeh-serve?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bokeh

I'm struggling with solving the following problem:
we'd like to embed Bokeh graphs into our django pages and we don't want to run sockets and bokeh-serve. We planned to replace the input updaters with custom javascript functions that would call $.ajax then trigger change.

However, `components()` only renders the plots not the inputs it seems. (If I put any inputs, it stops with error.) I decided to try and get the Backbone models of Bokeh from the outside, but I'm not sure how to do it, I'm a newbie at Backbone...

If you figured out how to properly embed plots with inputs please give me a hand.

Comment: Need to add more js and css from bokeh. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36716881/1031191