# How to make Bokeh work with a REST api backend instead of bokeh-serve?

Tags: bokeh

How can I make Bokeh work with my own REST api backend using CustomJS instead of bokeh-serve? `components()` do not seem to render inputs and inputs seem to come always with a need to run bokeh-serve.

Answer (score 3):

Barnabas, it is basically impossible to diagnose a problem if you do not provide actual code and describe *in extreme detail* what you have already tried. FWIW here is a minimal script that renders a Bokeh `Button` in a Flask app:

import flask

```
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.core.templates import FILE
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
from bokeh.util.string import encode_utf8

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def foo():
    button = Button(label="test")

    script, div = components(button, INLINE)
    html = FILE.render(
        plot_script=script,
        plot_div=div,
        bokeh_js=INLINE.render_js(),
        bokeh_css=INLINE.render_css(),
    )
    return encode_utf8(html)

app.run(debug=True)
```

There are things I'd certainly do different in a real deployment (no `INLINE` resources, e.g) but without additional information about your actual use-case or what you are really wanting to do it is impossible to offer additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that to use widgets one needs to include extra js and css to the html page.
In my case those are

- bokeh-0.11.1.min.js,
- bokeh-widgets-0.11.1.min.js
- bokeh-compiler-0.11.1.min.js and
- bokeh-widgets-0.11.1.min.css.